# what does Λ mean in a probability question?

Tags: probability

I study telecommunications and Λ symbol appear in probability questions and I do not know what it means. I looked at the book but there is no explanation nor example question with this symbol. I looked online and there is also no explanation. Here is a question from the book.

Random variable X is distributed according to Fx(x) = Λ(x), determine the probability that X is bigger than 0.5.

Can you tell me what I should understand from Λ.

Comment: Well, there are a couple of things called [Lambda Distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_distribution) but I seriously doubt that either of these are intended.  I don't think it is a universally used notation...I strongly imagine it is defined somewhere in your reference.

Comment: Maybe related to [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure)...

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: Maybe we have a random variable $X$ and a distribution function $F_X(x)=\text {Pr}(\{ X \le x\})$. If we call $\Lambda$ the *probability measure* (usually $\mu$) we have that: $F_X(x)= \Lambda( (- \infty, x])$.

Comment: Instead of just "from the book", it would be much more useful if you say *which* book it is.

Comment: it could also mean 'and' or 'min', see wedge and vee notation. note that 'and' between two events is the same as the 'min' between their indicator functions.